# How to send data queried from a database onto a webpage as email using python flask

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with python flask. i queried information from a database and displayed in an html web page. I am Having problem sending the queried data as an email using python flask. please help out

Comment: What exactly is this problem you're describing? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows people to reproduce the error or at least see what the problem is so they can suggest a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a mail server set up? You might want to check out [flask-mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/)

Assuming you're starting from the very beginning (because your question is not clear), install the package:

```
pip install Flask-Mail
```

After setting up your mail servers do the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail

app = Flask(__name__)
mail = Mail(app)
```

And then to send your queried information you can simply create a message this way:

```
from flask_mail import Message

@app.route("/") #whatever route you want
def email_query():
    subject = #your subject goes here
    message = #your query goes here
    msg = Message(recipients=['''email address of recipient goes here'''],
                      body=message,
                      subject=subject)
    mail.send(msg)
```